# Integrate FBX SDK to DirectX

Tags: mesh, fbx

I am working with FBX SDK 2013.3 and project on DirectX .

I need some basic knowledge,

Think that i have a cube, exported from Maya with .fbx extension, it has animation but problem isn't that now.

Now i need Load this .fbx file to DirectX, so indices,vertex positions must be handle.

I looked FBX SDK Documentations, Samples ( mostly ViewScene sample ) and i obtain some information.

```
const char* lFilename = ".\..\..\..\DuzZemin.fbx";  

/* Memory Management */
FbxManager* myManager = FbxManager::Create();

FbxIOSettings* ioSettings = FbxIOSettings::Create(myManager,IOSROOT);
myManager->SetIOSettings(ioSettings);

// Importer
FbxImporter* myImporter = FbxImporter::Create(myManager,"");

if( !myImporter->Initialize(lFilename,-1,ioSettings))
{
    /* Error Handling */
}

/* Scene for Imported File */

FbxScene* myScene = FbxScene::Create(myManager,"My Scene");


myImporter->Import(myScene);

    // Memory DeAllocation
myImporter->Destroy();


FbxNode* rootNode = myScene->GetRootNode();

FbxMesh* myMesh = FbxMesh::Create(myScene,"");

int indexCount = myMesh->GetControlPointsCount();
```

and when build this code snippet, i am not getting any error. But in runtime ,

indexCount return with 0 value.

Do you see any wrong or missed requirement ?

Thanks for interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you create a mesh, but you don't point it to a mesh in your scene. When i have loaded an .fbx file i create a mesh pointer and then go into my scene and grab the mesh. Consider this code.

```
FbxMesh* mesh;

FbxNode* node = myScene->GetRootNode()->GetChild(0);

//I want my mesh to be formed by triangles so i convert the mesh into triangles
FbxGeometryConverter lConverter(node->GetFbxManager());
lConverter.TriangulateInPlace(node);

mesh = node->GetMesh();
```

now you should be able to get a correct vertex count from your mesh, and be able to extract the vertices. NOTE: If your .fbx file consist of more than one mesh then you would need to iterate thru the scene untill you find the desired mesh.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, i solved my problem on this way, i couldn't look posts for 5-6 days. But this answer is solution exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
FbxMesh* mesh;

FbxNode* node = myScene->GetRootNode()->GetChild(0);

//I want my mesh to be formed by triangles so i convert the mesh into triangles
FbxGeometryConverter lConverter(node->GetFbxManager());
lConverter.TriangulateInPlace(node);

mesh = node->GetMesh();
```